# Why when I disabled bluetooth from startup applications does it still run on boot?

Tags: 12.10, startup, bluetooth

I saw Bluetooth in startup applications and disabled it, but the process is still run when I boot the system.

**Edit 1**
i disabled it via BUM, and still appear in bootchart, look at this  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwS0_GGz-wuDYkc5S2p2Y1JyYnM/edit?usp=sharing and most of services that i disabled via BUM

**Edit 2**
I uninstalled it before via ubuntu software center, but reinstalled automatically when update system

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please be a little bit more specific or detailed about whay you're trying to accomplish, or take a look at [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @The Lord of Time oh sorry, i will read it now

Comment: That's an autocomment from one of my scripts.  What you need to do is be more specific with what's going on and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @The Lord of Time Look at this https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwS0_GGz-wuDdzBZUFplRXNXOGM/edit and you will see "bluetoothd" and take time when boot system, i want to remove it

Comment: Please add further information by editing your question and not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of its damon
you can remove it from runway to forbid it to be executed
one of the graphical ways is using BootUp-manager ("bum") program you can install it from ubuntu software center. it's easy to use or if you don't use it at all just uninstall it

Comment: i did it before,i disabled it via BUM, and still appear in bootchart, look at this
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwS0_GGz-wuDYkc5S2p2Y1JyYnM/edit?usp=sharing  and most of services that i disabled via BUM appear in bootchart!!, may BUM not working properly

Comment: I uninstalled it before via ubuntu software center, but reinstalled automatically when update system

Comment: nothing to say. it is weird!. i have done it and works good